# Spring component scan using property not working for multiple base packages

Tags: java, spring, properties-file, component-scan

I want to read a variable which keeps the packages name to scan from a properties file:

```
pluginpackages=com.x.a,com.x.b
```

This does work neither with

```
<context:component-scan base-package="${pluginpackages}"/>
```

nor with

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "${pluginpackages}")
```

Any idea how to read multiple base packages from a property?

Comment: Did you try with # instead of $ ?